# How to change a sentence into a model name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to transform the string `product on sale` into `ProductOnSale` as a model name.

How to achieve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In case you have a model/class with this name, you can use [constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize) to convert it to class name, just by doing:

```
"product on sale".constantize
```

otherwise, for general `String`, you can do:

```
"product on sale".split(' ').collect(&:capitalize).join
```

In Rails env, you can do it in following way as well:

```
"product on sale".camelize.delete(' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

`modelize = "This is a string".titleize.delete(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
> s = "product on sale"
>  s.titleize.gsub(' ', '')
 => "ProductOnSale"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
> string = "product on sale"
> string.gsub(' ','_').classify
  => "ProductOnSale"
```